# delaying selenium test steps after 'update' linq query

Tags: linq, selenium-webdriver

I am working on selenium with c#.In a test script I need to reset outstanding balance of account in database and then do purchase transaction through UI and see the final balance showing on UI is decreased.
I ran update linq query and in the next steps I had written code to purchase product and checkout. This test case is passing in debug mode but failing in run mode. The final balance is not reducing when running the test case and it is reducing when debugging the test case. What is the issue.

Comment: I used System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(30000) after submitchanges () in linq query and it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can set a standard wait time, but you may find you're waiting way too long, making your tests slooooow, or your test will fail if your server has a slow down.

Try a loop to check if the update has been made:

```
var iterationCount = 10;
var iterationWaitTime = 250;
var hasChanged = false;
var currentValue = /*get current value*/;
var i = 0;

while (!hasChanged && i++ < iterationCount)
{
    var newValue = /*get new value*/;

    hasChanged = object.Equals(currentValue, newValue);
    currentValue = newValue;
}

Assert.IsTrue(!hasChanged && i++ < iterationCount, "No update detected");

/* do test on currentValue here */
```

(P.S. This is freehand so may not be perfectly correct)